# magento 2 credit card checkout error. (Invalid type for value: \"1\". Expected Type: \"int\".)

Tags: magento

magento 2 checkout page , credit card payment method is not working.
it is throwing error - {"message":"Invalid type for value: \"1\". Expected Type: \"int\"."}

order id is not passing on checkout. orderid- true.
I checked everything.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you precise what you tried, what is the code ? See  [ask]

Comment: order id is not passing on post request.

Answer (score 0):

You  have change data type in your "interface" from api, in definition input parameters. I let next example:

```
/**
 * GET definitions
 * @param string $customerId
 * @return string
 */
```

Additionally you need compile the project, so its works

good luck !